# ignore preceding spaces using negative lookbehind

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex

```
(?<![Ø])4
```

It works as expected when there is no spaces between Ø and 4, but I am trying to make it work the same way when there are n number of spaces between Ø and 4.

so the following shouldn't match

```
Ø4
Ø 4
Ø   4
Ø                                                                4
```

I tried using `\s*` but I get Lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed, whats the way to go?

Comment: Why fixed? Lookbehinds in .NET are not fixed width. Use `(?<![Ø]\s*)4`.

Comment: [Your regex works perfectly fine with `\s*`](http://ideone.com/nH62LV).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookbehinds in .NET are not fixed-width.

Use

```
(?<!Ø\s*)4
     ^^^
```

You may test it at [RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester).